# how to replace dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

sample dataframes are

```
df1= 
A  B  C
a0 b0 c0
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
...
an bn cn


df2=
A   B 
x0 y0
x1 y1
x2 y2
...
xm ym
```

What I want to replace is,

if (ai,bi) = (xj,yj) for some j, then ci = 0

For example,

```
df3= 
A  B  C
1  4 c0
2  8 c1
2  9 c2
3 12 c3
3 16 c4
4 16 c5


df4=
A   B 
2   8
3  12
```

and I would like to get below

```
result=
A  B  C
1  4 c0
2  8  0
2  9 c2
3 12  0
3 16 c4
4 16 c5
```

I couldn't find how to replace by using `np.where`. I need your help!

Comment: using left merge ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `fillna` and `drop_duplicates` you can do:

```
result = (pd.concat([df4,df3],ignore_index=True,sort=False)
            .fillna(0).drop_duplicates(['A','B'],keep='first'))
print (result)
   A   B   C
0  2   8   0
1  3  12   0
0  1   4  c0
2  2   9  c2
4  3  16  c4
5  4  16  c5
```

you can add `.sort_values(['A','B']).reset_index(drop=True)` at the end to get the exact same result

Using `merge` with the parameter `how='inner'` to get the index to change and then `loc` these index:

```
result = df3.copy()
result.loc[df3.reset_index().merge(df4,how='inner')['index'],'C'] = 0
print (result)
   A   B   C
0  1   4  c0
1  2   8   0
2  2   9  c2
3  3  12   0
4  3  16  c4
5  4  16  c5
```

Comment: Using 'isin' seems to be the general solution. Thanks for your big help!

Comment: Hmm... If df3 has element (2,12), 'isin' method gives 'True'.
Because 2 is in [2,3] , 12 is in [8,12].
But df4 does not have element (2,12), so this raise an error...

Comment: @DavidCho I added a solution that seems better to keep the order of the original `df3` and change the value in `result` using `merge`